# Grouping non-date data in a usable way for Excel Pivot Tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

I've got a large list of various department labels and associated data, and am wondering how best to consolidate this down to something simpler for reporting.

An excerpt of the data is in the below table. Here we have a bunch of different names used for Finance, but they can all simply be represented as "Finance".

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Finance - Accounts Payable        |
| Finance - Chief Financial Officer |
| Finance - Corporate               |
| Finance - Customs                 |
| Finance - Data Management         |
| Finance - Finance - Retail        |
| Finance - Finance Administration  |
| Finance - Finance Corporate       |
| Finance - Finance Retail          |
| Finance - Finance SS              |
| Finance - Finance, Corporate      |
| Finance - Finance, Retail         |
| Finance - Finance, SS             |
| Finance - Finance, Wholesale      |
| Finance - Planning and Reporting  |
| Finance - Retail                  |
| Finance - Shared Services         |
| Finance - Wholesale               |
| Finance ? Finance, Retail         |
| Finance Corporate                 |
| Finance SS                        |
| Finance, Corporate                |
| Finance, Shared Services          |
| Finance, Wholesale                |
+-----------------------------------+
```

I can't seem to find a good way to group this data (Pivot Table grouping doesn't seem useful for non-date data), so I'm wondering if I'm better off manipulating the data to replace all fields with one uniform name and then create a pivot table from the cleaned data.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @David Metcalfe,  this issue can be solved using SORT the Pivot Table,, better use Pivot Table & Chart wizard so that you can use Departments ( here is finance) to filter for their Categories ( here are second column),, if this works for you then plz confirm through comments , I'll post the method. ☺

Comment: @RajeshS That would work if I only wanted to report against any field containing "finance", but I want to consolidate the data into one name for several areas. There are multiple areas of the company that have this issue in the data (finance, wholesale, retail, corporate, etc), so I need a way to combine these so that I can then report against them in a pivot table, chart, etc.

Comment: Hi @David Metcalfe,, could U plzz share the expected OUTPUT will help me to understand you need in better way! I've used Department (Finance) in Column & the second Col as Row,, !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approximate match against your unique list of departments using XLOOKUP should give you what you want.

I created two named Tables:

1. roles, the list of roles which we want to group
2. depts, the unique list of departments to group by

The fifth parameter in this function tells XLOOKUP to look for an exact match or the next smallest item. As such, this formula will work well for roles that begin with the department name.

```
=XLOOKUP([@Name],depts[Departments],depts[Departments],"Dept not found",-1,1)
```

[image]

**EDIT: PowerQuery method for pre-Excel 365**

It just so happens I made a video about this exact process earlier today, so it's fresh in my mind.

You can use PowerQuery to do partial text matching without complicated Excel formulas.

First, create a connection-only query on your list of departments.

1. Put your cursor in the list
2. Use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range
3. In the Power Query Editor, click the drop-down on Home>Close & Load and use Close & Load To, then select "Only create connection"

Next, create a query on your list of data using the first and second steps listed above.

I have expanded the list from the XLOOKUP approach to include all your data plus the extras I added. The full list is in my workbook in a table called allroles. In Power Query I now have this:

[image: PQ]

Now use Add Column>General>Custom Column and use this formula:

```
Table.First(Table.SelectRows(
  depts,
  (lookup) => Text.Contains([Role],lookup[Departments])
))
```

Note that the reason we use `Table.First` here is to ensure that `Table.SelectRows` returns just one match for each Role. So, it's important that your list of Departments is sorted in the order of priority for matching. If you have Finance - Corporate, then in your list of departments you have Finance on one row, then Corporate on the next, the above formula will return Finance for that role. If Corporate were before Finance, it would return Corporate. If you removed the call to `Table.First`, it would return one row for Finance and a duplicate row categorized as Corporate. This is actually quite powerful but I suspect not exactly what you want.

To understand why we use SelectRows for this, it's important to remember that SelectRows is how PowerQuery filters data. So here, we are saying "filter the depts table and return the rows where the current role contains the value in the Departments column of the depts table". The `(lookup)` part is simply a named parameter referencing the depts table that allows us to refer to columns within that table from a column we're about to add to a completely different table (allroles).

When you click OK, you'll see a new column with the word Record in every row. If you've removed Table.First, it will say Table in every row.

Click the double-arrow at the top of the column, like this:

[image]

This will expand the record (or table), and show you the value returned by the custom function:

[image]

Now you can use Home>Close & Load to put the results back into the workbook.

Comment: Hi Flex. This appears to be a great solution for this problem, but it looks like `XLOOKUP` isn't available for me in the most up-to-date version of Excel 2016. Do you have a solution for cases where `XLOOKUP` isn't available?

Comment: Do you want to be able to assign more than one department text to a role? For example, if you had "Engineering, Wholesale", would you want to be able to categorize that row with both Engineering and Wholesale separately?

Comment: Thankfully, the data only includes one department per row, so that shouldn't be necessary. Hopefully, this will keep it simple.

Comment: OK. Is the department always the first word in the role?

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is a bit messy, so the department can be in different places within the cell. And sorry, I missed your earlier question, where we have "Finance, Wholesale" as an example. I would see this posing a problem but we consider Finance to be a department and Wholesale to be a line of business, so it still shouldn't be a problem. I could just have a pre-defined list to look against like your above example.

Comment: See my edit showing how to do this with PowerQuery. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'll just have to study how to use PowerQuery as the current configuration (and minor variants) results in errors instead of the desired results. This is likely just due to my ignorance of the tool. I'll mark this as the correct answer.